# In a data base how can reduce the redundency?

Tags: database, database-design

I have one table

```
Table 
Email_Address
Name
contact_No
city
Pincode
state
country
```

I divided into two parts

```
Table1
Email_Address(PK)
Name
contact_No
city

table2    
city
Pincode
state
country
```

how i can maintain the relationship between this table.

Answer (score 1):

`City` would be the **primary key** of `table2` and a **foreign key** in `Table1`. (But that requires city names to be globally unique and have only a single pincode each).

You need to be sure that a single `city` has only one `Pincode`.
If that is not the case, probably use the `Pincode` as primary/foreign key instead of `city`.

**Update:** Since apparently there are cases where some pincodes span multiple cities, you probably need to live with the redundancy or introduce an artificial key. Also see the links to similar questions here in the comments.

Comment: No on that first paragraph, otherwise you're going to get into trouble between Richmond in Virginia and Melbourne, or Perth in Western Australia and Scotland, or Springfield in a dozen different places in the US. The primary key needs to be _unique._

Comment: In the US, some zip codes (pincodes) cover several cities; other cities have multiple zip codes.  My zip code is used by two cities, both of which also have other zip codes.  And my zip code straddles a county boundary. I believe that there are zip codes that straddle two states.  Addresses are hard to handle (even in a single country, let alone internationally), mainly because humans are so inventive.  See also [SO 310540](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310540/best-practices-for-storing-postal-addresses-in-a-database-rdbms) Best Practices for Storing Postal Addresses in a Database.

Comment: Alternative question with better answers: [SO 929684](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929684/is-there-common-street-addresses-database-design-for-all-addresses-of-the-world) Is there a common street address database design for all addresses of the world?