# ISO Standard Street Addresses?

Tags: standards, iso

Is there an ISO standard address format?  I can't seem to find one, and I'd like to know for object- and database-design purposes.

(One interesting document that shows a bunch of formats is this: http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats.html, but it's insane!)

Comment: Given the variety of formats in use, I can't imagine an ISO standard for it getting passed, and even if one did it clearly wouldn't mean much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there common street addresses database design for all addresses of the world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929684/is-there-common-street-addresses-database-design-for-all-addresses-of-the-world)

Comment: There is no single standard, even at a very generic level. See: [falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No; each country defines its own standard.

There have been a number of questions about this in times past, including:

- [Best practices for storing postal addresses in an RDBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310540/best-practices-for-storing-postal-addresses-in-a-database-rdbms/)
- [Is there a common street address database design for all addresses of the world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929684/is-there-common-street-addresses-database-design-for-all-addresses-of-the-world/)

The second of those itself has references to a number of other SO questions.

You might want to check out the grandiosely named [Universal Postal Union](http://www.upu.int/en/activities/standards/about-standards.html) and its standards.

Comment: I did come across the UPU site in searching around, but I was intimidated by it.  "Grandiose" is apt.  I don't suppose you could point me towards a page on the site that I should read?

Comment: See [SO 929684](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929684/is-there-common-street-addresses-database-design-for-all-addresses-of-the-world), which is referenced from the second question above.  Also [here](http://www.upu.int/en/resources/postcodes/about-postcodes.html) under the UPU web site.

Answer (score 10):

**There are none**. However, you can also consider that place is usually contained in a bigger place.

So, you can also use the hierarchical structure of places in following an address format. Which also means it differs from country-to-country.

You can read stuffs about this on:

- **Universal Postal Union**'s paper [Addressing the world, an address for everyone](https://www.upu.int/UPU/media/upu/publications/whitePaperAddressingTheWorldEn.pdf)
- [Place ontology from schema.org](http://schema.org/Place)
- [PostalAddress ontology from schema.org](http://schema.org/PostalAddress)
- [ISO 19160-4 standard](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/en/#iso:std:iso:19160:-4:ed-2:v1:en)

## 2023 Update

There is a new technological concept on this area. Some consider such solutions as *de facto* standards. The new concept is to use longitude and latitude coordinates to specifically pinpoint a location. However, since longitude and latitude coordinates are difficult to remember, you need to use a representation of these coordinates. Such solutions are:

| **Representation** | **Vendor** | **Example raw identifier** | **Example** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Plus codes | [Google](https://maps.google.com/pluscodes/) | `HXJG+GFF` | HXJG+GFF, Roxas Blvd, Ermita, Manila, 1000 Metro Manila |
| 3 words | [what3words](https://what3words.com/about) | `///storage.gazette.icons` | ///storage.gazette.icons, Roxas Blvd, Ermita, Manila, 1000 Metro Manila |

Using such geocoordinates representations will make the names of the administrative locations as just mere supplementary details.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the address below.

Address standards
A collection of information on address standards
ISO 19160, Addressing

https://standards.iso.org/iso/19160/

http://www.isotc211.org/

Comment: Your post is interesting, although the draft has barely made it beyond the basic-structure level. As it stands, it's of no help.