# Is there a standard for job sectors?

Tags: database-design, standards, jobs, iso

Is there any sort of recognised standard for grouping jobs into job sectors e.g. 'technology', 'emergency services'? I'm looking to use this in a program I'm working on.

Closest I can find is [this](https://www.prospects.ac.uk/jobs-and-work-experience/job-sectors), but I want to know if there's an official standard.

Comment: Voting to close - completely offtopic because it's about ISO standards.

Comment: I would think that the following SE is more appropriate: http://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure this was the right SE, but couldn't find a better one (@JohnColeman there's no relevant tags on Economics SE). There are a lot of ISO questions on SO (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840928/iso-standard-street-addresses) and I'm looking to use the standard for categorising data in a program.

Comment: Economies change so rapidly and vary so much from country to country that I think the idea of official standards is unlikely. On the other hand, certain sectors are used various official reports, and the economics stack exchange seems like a good place to ask, even if they lack a tag that seems directly relevant.

Comment: This isn't ISO, but seems somewhat official: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Industrial_Classification  . Also -- this also seems relevant, though US-centered: http://siccode.com/en/siccode/list/directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an international standard for job classifications, but not by ISO, it's by the International Labour Organization

http://www.ilo.org/public/english/bureau/stat/isco/index.htm

Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Classification_of_Occupations

Search "isco-08 excel" to get the data