# JavaScript; Regex only string of 5 digits side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var src = document.getElementById("one"),
                    dst = document.getElementById("two");
                src.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    dst.value = src.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <input type="text" id="one" name="one">
        <input type="text" id="two" name="two">
    
    </body>
</html>
```

This will remove everything that isn't a digit from `one` and insert in `two`.

But I want to keep only a string of five digits side by side.

Means, if `one` is:

`test 1 test 1234 test`; no output

`test 1 12345 test`; output `12345`

`test 123456 test 12 test`; no output

`12394 test`; output `12394`

`84725`; output `84725`

Does anybody know how to change the REGEX to reach this?

Comment: Hi David, I believe you deleted your old question and reposted this one. You’re trying to parse the zip/postal code from an address field. While your suggestion may work, here are a few caveats: 1. 5 digit house numbers (i.e. `12345 Some street`); 2. Zip codes have different formats in different countries (i.e. in Canada: `A0A 0A0`)

Comment: You really should look at this question about addresses and databases so that you can properly organize your address code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310540/best-practices-for-storing-postal-addresses-in-a-database-rdbms you **WILL** run into issues if you decide to make it US only and if you use regex to parse zip codes, that’s a **guarantee**

Comment: @ctwheels I already do. I have different columns in ma database for address and zip. This code is for the "insert into database" form. Normally I copy the zip manually in the zip text field. Now I'll have less work. Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\d` to match digits, and specify the length of your choice with `{5}`. Then, word boundaries (`\b`) make sure that there is no other digit adjacent to you matches:

[`/\b\d{5}\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/l1Qf2H/3)

Comment: This can be shortened to `\b\d{5}\b` - the `[]` isn’t necessary since the set only contains one value

Answer (score 0):

For your specific use case you can use `\b(\d{5})\b/g` to capture the required values in the capture group. Otherwise the matched values will have spaces.

Comment: This is incorrect due to the fact that there may or may not be a space next to the digits. The correct answer is to use `\b` instead of `\s` since it can be found at the beginning or end of a string (nothing before/after it), it could have a comma or some other non-word character following it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
  var src = document.getElementById("one"),
  dst = document.getElementById("two");
  src.addEventListener('input', function() {
   dst.value = src.value.match(/\b\d{5}\b/g);
});
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="one" name="one">
<input type="text" id="two" name="two">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You better accept @jeffrey-westerkamp answer, because your answer in based on his regex.